# Proper way to extend Controllers zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, inheritance

I am trying to extend a controller, so my IndexController looks like

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
   public function IndexAction()
   {
       //Add a few css files
       //Add a few js files
   }

   public function LoginAction()
   {
       //Login stuff
   }
}
```

Now when i try doing:

```
require_once("IndexController.php");
class DerivedController extends IndexController
{
    public function IndexAction()
    {
         //Override index stuff, and use the dervied/index.phtml
    } 
}
```

And call `derived/login` I get

```
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' \
 with message 'script 'derived/login.phtml' not found in path`
```

So to solve this I say oh thats ok I can force login to use its own view. Then I think, this is easy all I gota do inside `IndexController::LoginAction` is add:

```
$this->view->render('index/login.phtml');
```

But It still tries to look for `derived/login.phtml`.

Just to expand on this a little more, I only want the Actions which are defined in `DerivedController` to use `derived/<action>.phtml` but everything else such as `LoginAction` to use `<originalcontroller>/<action>.phtml`

Should I be doing things differently? or Am I missing a small step?

**Note** If I add `derived/login.phtml` or symlink it from `index/login.phtml` it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to re-use all view (*.phtml) files from `IndexController` you could overwrite the ScriptPath inside the cunstructor and point it to the correct (indexcontroller) folder:

```
class DerivedController extends IndexController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_view = new Zend_View(); 
        $this->_view->setScriptPath($yourpath);
    }

[...]

    public function IndexAction()
    {
         //Override inherited IndexAction from IndexController
    }

[...]

}
```

---

Edit:

Try using a simple conditional inside predispatch:

```
class DerivedController extends IndexController
{

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        if (!$path = $this->getScriptPath('...')) { 
            //not found ... set scriptpath to index folder 
        }

        [...]

    }

[...]

}
```

this way you could check if `derived/<action>.phtml` exists, otherwiese set the script path to use `index/<action>.phtml`.

Comment: Sorry I am not trying to reuse all the `*.phtml` files I am trying to overwrite them. And any Actions that are not overwritten to use their original controller `.phtml` file.

Comment: But to do your edit, I have to overwrite each action. That I don't want to overwrite

Comment: No. You don't have to. Just put these lines of code inside the public `preDispatch()` function and it'll get executed *before* dispatching the called function. No need to owerwrite all inherited functions. I've addited it to my answer

Comment: Ok sort of worked, Turns out I was using the wrong function inside the IndexController::LoginAction, I was using `$this->view->render('index/login.phtml');` instead of `$this->renderScript('index/login.phtml');`. However having said that I like your predispatch idea, where if the script is not found, it fallbacks to the `index/` counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

How can a class can extend an Action It should be

```
class DerivedController extends IndexController
```

and not

```
class DerivedController extends IndexAction
```

Comment: Sorry that was a type, +1 for spotting it

Answer (score 1):

`DerivedController` should extend the CLASS `IndexController` not one function (IndexAction).  This way you don't need any `require_once()`.

Correct way:

```
class DerivedController extends IndexController
{
    public function IndexAction()
    {
         //Override inherited IndexAction from IndexController
    } 
}
```

Comment: Okay. Have you tried setting the script path inside `DerivedController` to point to the view folder of indexcontroller?

Take a look at `setScriptPath()`

Comment: Yes I did, but that will do something different, I want login to pick up index/login.phtml, where as anything which is overwritten in derived to use derived/<action>.phtml

Comment: If you`re inheriting & using all functions you could add it into constructor ... see my other answer.